# Spring 3.1 Type Level RequestMapping and logical view names

Tags: java, spring-mvc

a question about type-level wildcard request mapping and Springs logical view names derived from void and domain object returns. Say I have the following

```
@Controller
class HomeController
{
    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public void index () {}
}
```

My understanding of how Springs logical view name generation is that the above controller will map "/" to the logical view name "index" which I can then, for example, use Apache Tiles to match against an appropriate jsp view.

Similarly, this demonstrates my understanding of Springs logical view name creation (but I think I'm missing something...)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/collection/*")
class CollectionController
{

    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Item> list ()
    {
        // in my understanding
        // itemList should be available in the model (via generated name),
        // that the logical view name generated should be
        // collection/list and that this method
        // would intercept the url "/collection/" or "/collection"
        return someService.getItems();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/{itemId}")
    public Item item (@PathVariable final String itemId)
    {
        // similiarly, item should be available in the
        // model and the logical view name should be
        // collection/item
        return someService.getItem(itemId);
    }
}
```

Thing is, is that the list method is never resolved as the 'index' page of the collection- instead, the logical view name appears to be "collection" (which I havent defined- I want the logical view name to be "collection/list". The 'item' method works- its just that the index page does not- sorry for the vague question- not sure how else to put it-

How can I take advantage of Springs logical view name generation from method names based on wildcard urls on the type level without returning strings to define the logical view name? The above does not work the way I expected. What am I missing?

UPDATE:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{

    static private String [] TILES_DEFINITIONS= new String [] { "/WEB-INF/layouts/tiles.xml", "/WEB-INF/views/**/tiles.xml"};

    /* static resource resolution */ 
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) 
    {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    /**
     * ViewResolver configuration required to work with Tiles2-based views.
     */
    @Bean  
    public ViewResolver viewResolver ()
    {
        UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver= new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    /**
     * Configures Tiles at application startup.
     */
    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer () 
    {
        final TilesConfigurer configurer= new TilesConfigurer();
        configurer.setDefinitions(TILES_DEFINITIONS);
        configurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
        return configurer;
    }
}
```

And my tiles folder structure is

```
src/main/webapp/layouts (contains base page.jsp)
```

and

```
src/main/webapp/views/[VIEWNAME]/tiles.xml
```

where VIEWNAME is a view name (sorry!) and view paths for that view name are defined in that folders tiles.xml. Hope that makes things clearer...

Comment: Can you please show how you have configured the ViewResolver to render your views. After seeing that I can answer something.

Comment: There you go Japan- hope that helps- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, your list method is set to respond to GET of /collections, and you want to take advantage of the default view name resolution, but want a view name which is not the same as one resolved by default -

The default resolution is based on the http path to where the request is sent (in your case `/collections`), and the view would be `collections` , if instead the GET request were sent to `/collections/list` , your view name would have been `collections/list`. You can look at the API for [DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator.html) for more information on the rules.

In your case however, you want the request sent to `/collections` be resolved as a `collections/list` view name.

I can see only one way of doing it - to explicitly return the view name from the method  `return "collections/list";`

You can try writing a custom RequestToViewNameTranslator, but the parameter passed to is the httprequest, and you cannot derive much from it, to construct something like what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Biju- I was beginning to suspect as much. Just to clarify, the list method, simply annotated with RequestMethod.GET, would generate the logical view name "campaigns", and the method name "list" would not factor into the logical view name unless I explicitly returned either a string "collections/list" or ModelAndView with viewName set to "collections/list"... right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. the method would respond to any GETS to `/collections/*`(`/collections`, '`/collections/list` etc). You can return either a `collections/list` string, like you said or a ModelAndView with viewName set to `collections/list`